# How to make a YouTube chromeless player?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

This may sound stupid but I looked online for some time and I could not find how to make a YouTube player chromeless. I am making a web app and I am using the YouTube JavaScript API. Wherever I look online for some information on how to actually make the player chromeless, it just gives me information on how to operate with a chromeless player. Nobody addresses this question (it seems to be obvious), but I just can't figure out how to do it. Could someone please explain to me how to do it (do I need to pass a certain parameter somewhere?) Thanks.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference

Comment: This is a post about this topic that you may find useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626966/how-do-i-go-about-embedding-a-youtube-chromeless-player-without-adding-controls

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I go about embedding a youtube chromeless player without adding controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626966/how-do-i-go-about-embedding-a-youtube-chromeless-player-without-adding-controls)

Answer (score 5):

Alright, so I figured it out. So, if you are using JavaScript as I did (I believe it also works for AS3), simply, instead of writig the video ID in the URL (the one that you give to the embedswf() function), write "apiplayer". Then, after the video player has loaded, simply call the function cueVideo() on it (passing it the video ID of the video you want to show). This will make the video player chromeless.

Answer (score 1):

Well first you would the HTML Code

```
<embed src=""/>
```

Now this takes the url: 
http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?enablejsapi=1&version=3

This one doesn't take a ID due to the fact you give it one in JS on the function

```
onYouTubePlayerReady()
```

Here is a little example

```
<script>
onYouTubePlayerReady = initializePlayer;
function initializePlayer(){
var video = document.getElementById('video');
video.loadVideoById(String id , int starttime , string quality);
var playbutton = document.getElementById('playbtn');
playbutton.addEventListener('click' , playVideo());
var pausebutton = document.getElementById('psbtn');
pausebutton.addEventListener('click' , pauseVideo());
}
</script>
```

That is the basic script, hope this works!